# PHP get week numbers and dates by year

Tags: php, time

I was wondering how i can get all week numbers and dates where the week start and ends on. I am completely empty on the code, so I cannot show you anything. I need to get something like this website: http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the following, just change the year to any year you like.

```
<?php

$year = 2014;

$weeks = getIsoWeeksInYear($year);

for($x=1; $x<=$weeks; $x++){
    $dates = getStartAndEndDate($x, $year);
    echo $x . " - " . $dates['week_start'] . ' - ' . $dates['week_end'] . "<br>";
}

function getIsoWeeksInYear($year) {
    $date = new DateTime;
    $date->setISODate($year, 53);
    return ($date->format("W") === "53" ? 53 : 52);
}

function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->setISODate($year, $week)->format('Y-m-d');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->modify('+6 days')->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your getIsoWeeksInYear does not work, when the first week starts in December 2014

Comment: Week 01 December 29, 2014 - January 4, 2015

Comment: yeah I have been searching around on the web and see a lot of different calendars. [calendar 1](http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php?year=2014), [calendar 2](http://www.calendar-365.com/2014-calendar.html) So I'm not sure which one is the correct one.

Comment: @SørenEfa I changed it to have the same dates as your link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$week = 1;
$year = 2014;
while($week <= 52)
{
        $time = strtotime("26 December $year", time());
        $day = date('w', $time);
        $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
        $start = date('Y-n-j', $time);
        $time += 6*24*3600;
        $end = date('Y-n-j', $time);

echo "weekno : ".$week." start date : ".$start." End date : ".$end."<br/>";
$week++;
$year++;
}
```

Comment: 2015 has 53 weeks and the first week starts in 2014.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make the $time automatic change?

Comment: @Søren Efa the $time will change automatically.